# How to fix faulty base64 urls received by client?

Tags: string, url, base64, hex, html-email

This issue is somewhat foggy, but I hope I can get some help or directions here.

My service generates and sends unsubscribe links to recipients alongside the actual email. Unsubscribe link is composed of base url and a random hexstring extension, which is unique to every recipient. Some recipients receives the unsubscribe link extensions converted to base64 strings and the extensions are cut to just 10 characters. This of course prevents them from unsubscribing, which is not desired.

This is the case with few recipients only, so I guess the problem is in how their email client handles the email. Any idea what could be causing this and how to approach this problem?

Comment: Are the problem email clients all the same one, and if so which one is it?

Comment: This actually something I don't know. I can't get that information from anywhere. I just know that the extension is changed, because the unsubscribe function logs it as error when it encounters a faulty hex string extension. From the error I see that the extension is the start of the base64 encoded hex string. At the moment I am exploring the behavior of spam filters and mobile email clients, if they are somehow causing this.

Comment: Old issue, but I currently have the same problem almost 6 years later. Some unknown email client behaves like this: From a long link in an email (say /aaa/bbb/my-cute-page), the last segment is converted to base64, and shortened to just 10 characters, resulting in /aaa/bbb/bXktY3V0ZS, which of course creates a 404 error. My client tells me it might be their sensitive email filtering system, they've had this issue in the past. Can't find out more at this point. Did you ever solve this? @zaplec

Comment: I can't remember anymore. I guess I didn't, because I haven't posted anything here after that @henk